# Is there an enhanced interpreter toploop for OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, ledit

Python has [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/).. does OCaml have anything similar?

I'd very much like to have command history, although other features would be nice too. I've read that I could get command history by running it in Emacs, but I don't use Emacs..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/) gives you readline features (history, editing commands, etc). Also, [Findlib](http://www.camlcity.org/archive/programming/findlib.html) adds some functionality, see the [quickstart](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.2.1/doc/guide-html/quickstart.html) for examples.

Comment: How do I use rlwrap to get command history when I'm in the OCaml interpreter?

Comment: I'm that Arthur Collé has found the answer by now, but for someone else who happens to be looking for the same answer in the future, one would run ocaml like this from shell prompt: `rlwrap ocaml`.

Answer (score 21):

There's [utop](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/utop/)! It has autocompletion, is emacs compatible and so on.

Comment: it's great. but its dependency looks really complex

Comment: I second utop. You can use opam to install utop as well as many other ocaml packages. http://opam.ocamlpro.com/

Answer (score 9):

Use `ledit ocaml` with [ledit](http://cristal.inria.fr/~ddr/ledit/).

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the online [toplevel](http://try.ocamlpro.com/).

Comment: Yes. Actually, the sources are available on [github](https://github.com/OCamlPro/tryocaml) if anyone is interested.